# display circle in center with flex [responsive]

Tags: css

How to have a circle in center of page using flex box and that has to be responsive ? I tried below but it did not work out.

HTML

```
<div class="circle">Hello I am A Circle </div>
```

CSS

```
   .circle {
        width:50px;
        height:50px;
        border-radius:100%;
        font-size:50px;
        color:#fff;
        line-height:500px;
        text-align:center;
        background:#000;
        flex:1;
        justify-content:center;
        align-items:center;
   }
```

Comment: Can you show the parent element? `justify-content` and `align-items` should be on the parent which needs `display: flex` to actually use flexbox.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flexbox: center horizontally and vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026884/flexbox-center-horizontally-and-vertically)

Comment: https://codepen.io/devvue/pen/vYGBqoe see this please, this is not working..it is still stays on top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your container a specific `height` and you'll see that your code is working as intended. The problem is that your container is only as big as the circle, so you won't notice until you make the container bigger. Try making it something `500px` tall.

Comment: here is what I did so far codepen.io/devvue/pen/vYGBqoe

Comment: Modify your container class to see that it's working:.container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 500px;
  background: #000;
}